# How do you work out the product of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got a question in my maths paper and I didn't know how to answer it. This was the question:

---

What is: $(1+\frac{1}{2}) (1+\frac{1}{3}) (1+\frac{1}{4}) $... All the way up to 98 factors

a) What is the product up to 98 terms

b) What is the product up to n terms

Comment: $$\dfrac32\cdot\dfrac43\cdot\dfrac54=?$$

Comment: In the future use MathJax to format your text: [Click here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee 5/2?

Comment: @DemetrioMacGuire, What is important: which terms survive in the numerator  & the denominator

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The numerator of the last one? and 2 at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question presented here seems to be a finite product. This can be written in the following notation:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$$

Where $N = $ the term you wish to calculate the series up to. In case $A$, N = 98

---

Let's work out the series up to:

N=1: $(1+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{3}{2}$

N=2: $ \frac{3}{2} * (1+\frac{1}{3}) = 2$

N=3: $ 2 * (1+\frac{1}{4}) =  \frac{5}{2}$

We can see that each term increments by $ \frac{1}{2}$ And so our N-th term can be written as:
$Tn = 0.5n + 1$

Therefore $T98 = 0.5(98) + 1 = 50$

Answer (score 2):

Start with
Joshua Lochner's
product:
$\prod_{n=1}^{N}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})
$.

Then manipulate it like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{n=1}^{N}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})
&=\prod_{n=1}^{N}(\frac{n+2}{n+1})\\
&=\frac{\prod_{n=1}^{N}(n+2)}{\prod_{n=1}^{N}(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{n=2}^{N+1}(n+1)}{\prod_{n=1}^{N}(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{\left(\prod_{n=2}^{N}(n+1)\right)(N+2)}{2\prod_{n=2}^{N}(n+1)}
\qquad\text{Isolate the common terms in each product}\\
&=\frac{(N+2)}{2}\\
&=\frac{N}{2}+1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Wow I did not think of that! Great stuff! Is there a way to do something similar for: $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (\frac{\pi}{3})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (\frac{\pi}{3})^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$ It's part of a question I am trying to answer here: [Click me :)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863129/the-relationship-between-tanx-and-square-roots)

Comment: Look up multisection of series.